# How to replace the color of non transparent pixels of a PDF

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have a pdf file which contains a white graphic over a transparent background and I am trying to find a way to replicate the same pdf except replacing the non transparent white pixels with black ones. 
I have been using imagemagick convert to convert the pdf into a png alpha, extracting the alpha channel and negating it with 300+ dpi, but it's ain't enough, since the vector object/s are rasterised and the quality is degraded.

I tried using ghostscript with pdfwrite but I couldn't find the right postscript command that would allow me to solve the issue.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ghostscript always rasterizes.

Comment: No, Ghostscript does **not** 'always rasterise'. The pdfwrite device retains pretty much everything 'as is', the (e)ps2write device retains everything except those aspects of the PDF graphcis model which cannot be represented in PostScript. Of course, when using ImageMagick, which is a btimap editing program, **that** tells Ghostscript to produce an image. If you want to edit a PDF file, you have to edit the PDF file, you can't use an image editor to do it. You certainly can't do what you want with Ghostscript, or at least not easily. Maybe with Acrobat Pro.

Comment: Producing a PNG with an alpha channel is insufficient to reproduce the rich transparency model of PDF. So the PNG will be rendered to a raster. In this case the only part of the resuilting PNG which will be 'transparent' is any portion of the output which had no marks drawn on it.